# How to show relevant results when searching

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have a project that contains an input and an array. When I search inside the input for something, I want it to show me the relevant results in the array based on the common characters

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" />
<div></div>
```

```
$(document).on("keyup keypress","input",function()
{
  let input = $(this)
  
  let array = ["tide","taet","oks","mos"]  
  
  storage = ""
  
  for( let x = 0; x < array.length; x++ )
    { 
      if( input.val() === array[x] )
        {
          storage = array[x] // I will use the stored text later
          
           $("div").append(`<p>this is : ${array[x]}</p>`)
          
          return
        }
      
        if( input.val() !== array[x] )
        {
           $("div").empty()
        }
    }
});
```

By the way, the code works, but it does not show me the results until I type the entire word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your if condition is trying to match the input to the whole array string. So it will only work once the entire string value from the array is typed.

```
if( input.val() === array[x] )
```

Try instead to check if the string from the input is contained within the array value.

```
if( array[x].includes( input.val() ) )
```

Comment: Great, it works. Can you give me sources for the includes() code? But how can I implement the second condition if the previous condition is not provided?

Comment: Because the first condition was: If there is a match between what is in the array and what is written in the input, then show me the results inside the p, but if the results written in the input do not match the elements inside the array, then delete the contents from the div, so how will I Does the second condition work for me? Because I tried several ideas and it didn't work

Comment: i tried this : !array[x].includes( input.val() ) - and dont work

Comment: and this : array[x].includes( !input.val() )

Comment: @erorprograms You could get rid of the second if statement all together and instead have the `$("div").empty()` right before the for loop. This way on each change you'd empty the div and then only if you found something you'd append the divs.

Comment: Hmmm, I apologize for the error. It seems that the solution did not work. Here is a link to the project so you can try it yourself, to save time of course: https://codepen.io/emozlove/pen/dyaRMmv

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, I understood the problem. The problem can be found in the return that I placed. If I remove it, then all the problems will disappear. I forgot about it because of the presence of the second conditional function, which was causing me problems and errors. I understand now. The world of programming is very interesting. A simple error may occur. It distorts the course of the entire project haha

Comment: Thank you, your solution is correct and I will choose you as the best answer, thank you